# Two basic questions regarding spectral sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I am reading the wonderful article [Spectral sequences : friend or foe ?](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216ss.pdf) by Ravi Vakil. However I do not understand the notation used when on p.4 he says :

> More precisely, there is a filtration $E_\infty^{o,k} \overset{E_\infty^{1,k-1}}{\hookrightarrow} ? \overset{E_\infty^{2,k-2}}{\hookrightarrow} ... \hookrightarrow H^k(E^{.})$ where quotients are displayed above each inclusion.

What does this statement mean ? I do not know the meaning of 'filtration' and do not understand which quotients are being talked about.

> My second question is the following. He mentions that in general there is no isomorphism between $_{>}E_\infty^{p,q}$ and $_{\wedge}E_\infty^{p,q}$. Why is it,then, that in the proof of snake lemma the vanishing of the first horizontal page implies that the vertical pages stabilize to the page with all entries 0 ?

I am a novice to this subject, so please excuse my silly questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be some object in a nice (e.g., abelian) category.  An *(ascending) filtration* of $H$ is a collection $(F_i)$ of subobjects $$F_0 \subset F_1 \subset \cdots \subset H.$$

In your example, it is asserted that $H = H^k(E^\bullet)$ has a filtration of length $k+1$ given by $(F_i)_{0 \leq i \leq k}$ with $F_0 = E_\infty^{0,k}$ and $F_k = H^k(E^\bullet)$.  Moreover, the filtration quotients are known: there are short exact sequences
\begin{gather*}
0 \to F_0 \to F_1 \to E_\infty^{1,k-1} \to 0 \\
0 \to F_1 \to F_2 \to E_\infty^{2,k-2} \to 0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \to F_{k-1} \to F_k \to E_\infty^{k,0} \to 0.
\end{gather*}

In principle, knowledge of the associated graded will let you reconstruct the filtered object $H$, up to extension problems.

As for your second question, while there is no isomorphism between the $E_\infty$-pages of the horizontal and vertical filtrations, the two spectral sequences must converge (if they converge) to the same object, in this case the cohomology $H^\bullet(E^\bullet)$ of the total complex.

In the example of the proof of the snake lemma, we know from the horizontal filtration that $H^\bullet(E^\bullet) = 0$.  This implies that we must have $E_\infty = 0$ for the vertical filtration as well (otherwise we would get $H^\bullet(E^\bullet) \neq 0$).  Then you can use this to deduce the existence of certain differentials that may not have been evident otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very clear explanation ! I understand it now